# WP Создание шаблона для кастомной рубрики

Tags: php, wordpress

Как задать шаблон для [кастомной рубрики(таксономии)](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_taxonomy) ?  Есть вот такой пример

```
/*
 *  Регистрация таксономии производителей
 */
add_action( 'init', 'create_vendor_taxonomies' );

// функция, создающая таксономии "vendors" для постов типа "vendor"
function create_vendor_taxonomies(){
    // Добавляем недревовидную таксономию 'vendors' (как метки)
    register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendor', 'post'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => false,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Производители', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Vendor', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Поиск производителей' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'Все производители' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Править производителя' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Обновить производителя' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Добавить нового производителя' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'Имя нового производителя' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendors' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
//      'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'vendors', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => false ),
    ));
}
```

Сама рубрика создалась. На её потомков по типу `https://site.loc/vendors/samsung/` я попасть могу, за них отвечает шаблон `taxonomy-vendors.php`
А вот как попасть на `https://site.loc/vendors/`  ? Отдает 404 страницу. [По иерархии пробовал](https://wp-kama.ru/id_7654/ierarhiya-fajlov-temy-shablona.html) archive-vendors.php category-vendors.php не помогло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все правильно. `site.loc/vendors/` - это страница или запись. Её у тебя нет. Архив таксономии  `site.loc/category/vendors/`

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Да добавил `page-vendors.php` заработало